# R define a new variable as count starting when condition is met

Tags: r, count, conditional-statements, survival-analysis

so I´m trying to add two new variables to my dataframe. A variable named `start`, which is supposed to be a a running count from 0 to whatever number of rows there are for one group, and a second variable named `stop` which is practically the same, but starting at 1. The count should start, once the value of a second variable scores >0. It is further important, that the count continues until the last value of the group (so it shouldn´t stop if `Var1=0` again) and that `NA`s are ignored in the sense, that counting continues.
Consider the following dataset as an example

```
ID    Var1   start   stop
1      0
1      1       0      1
1      4       1      2 
1      2       2      3
1      NA      3      4
1      4       4      5
2      0
2      0
2      3       0      1
2      5       1      2
2      9       2      3
2      0       3      4
```

I don´t really care for the values `start` and `stop` take on before `Var1>0` first, so whether it´s `0` or `NA` is not important

Thanks very much for the good answers in advance!!

Comment: look into rle, turn the data into 1 or 0, then rle the result, then seq_along or something on the lengths, ad this vector to your column, I can solve this later

Answer (score 0):

Dirty solution to the problem, will probably work just take out the extra columns that I made as steps with select

```r
library(tidyverse)


df_example <- read_table("ID    Var1   start   stop
1      0
1      1       0      1
1      4       1      2 
1      2       2      3
1      NA      3      4
1      4       4      5
2      0
2      0
2      3       0      1
2      5       1      2
2      9       2      3
2      0       3      4")

df_example %>%
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(greater_1 = if_else(replace_na(Var1,1) > 0,1,0),
         run_sum = cumsum(greater_1),
         to_fill = if_else(run_sum == 1,1,NA_real_)) %>% 
  fill(to_fill) %>% 
  mutate(end2 = cumsum(to_fill %>% replace_na(0)),
         star2 = if_else(end2 -1 > 0,end2 -1,0))
#> # A tibble: 12 x 9
#> # Groups:   ID [2]
#>       ID  Var1 start  stop greater_1 run_sum to_fill  end2 star2
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1     1     0    NA    NA         0       0      NA     0     0
#>  2     1     1     0     1         1       1       1     1     0
#>  3     1     4     1     2         1       2       1     2     1
#>  4     1     2     2     3         1       3       1     3     2
#>  5     1    NA     3     4         1       4       1     4     3
#>  6     1     4     4     5         1       5       1     5     4
#>  7     2     0    NA    NA         0       0      NA     0     0
#>  8     2     0    NA    NA         0       0      NA     0     0
#>  9     2     3     0     1         1       1       1     1     0
#> 10     2     5     1     2         1       2       1     2     1
#> 11     2     9     2     3         1       3       1     3     2
#> 12     2     0     3     4         0       3       1     4     3
```

<sup>Created on 2020-08-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>